# Android SQLite - creating two tables at once

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create two SLite tables at once in `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)` function in object extending SQLiteOpenHelper but it stops during first creation of table DB object(it work fine when I comment out the second query)

This is my onCreate function:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE users ( userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, login TEXT, password TEXT, name TEXT, "
            + "phone TEXT, country TEXT, balance TEXT)";

    String query2 = "CREATE TABLE transactions ( transactionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + "from TEXT, to TEXT, amount TEXT, title TEXT)";

    database.execSQL(query);
    database.execSQL(query2);
}
```

I've also tried to put this in one query like this:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE users ( userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, login TEXT, password TEXT, name TEXT, "
                + "phone TEXT, country TEXT, balance TEXT) CREATE TABLE transactions ( transactionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + "from TEXT, to TEXT, amount TEXT, title TEXT)";
```

then it works but stops my app when I want to get data from `transactions` table (`users` table works fine though)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us yours error from logCat

Comment: @mohax I am using real phone not emulator so I don't have error log

Comment: @NobuGames I have tried using statement with semicolon but it didn't work

Comment: @NobuGames the **;** is completely **useless**. As you correctly reported, `only "a single statement" is allowed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Column name your specify in query 2 "from" and "to" are key words.

So try your query2 like below.

```
 String query2 = "CREATE TABLE transactions ( transactionID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + "'from' TEXT, 'to' TEXT, amount TEXT, title TEXT)";
```